# Add tag to every TODO in file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have my `org-mode agenda` set up to include every `.org` file in my main directory where I keep files for each project.

I'd like to be able to see the agenda for a single project.

The only way I can see to do this is to add a project tag to each todo in a file.

Is there a function for adding a tag to every `TODO` in a file?

Is there a better way to accomplish this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tagging by file/project, you can build a single file agenda with the commands:

```
C-c a
```

when prompted for the specific option use

```
<
```

This will

> Restrict an agenda command to the current buffer. After pressing <, you still need to press the character selecting the command.

from the [org-mode docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-dispatcher.html#Agenda-dispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the headline of the project.

Press    `C-c a < < a`

This will give you the agenda view for the current subtree (i.e. for your project) only.